# Variable QMAKE_CXX.COMPILER_MACROS is not defined with QT 5.9.1 in MAC

Tags: xcode, macos, qt

In MAC machine I installed QT5 using brew install qt5.
When building the project using Xcode I am getting the error "Variable QMAKE_CXX.COMPILER_MACROS is not defined".

How to resolve this problem.